# calculate $x^{206}+x^{200}+x^{90}+x^{84}+x^{18}+x^{12}+x^{6}+1$ given $(x+x^{-1})^2 = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

If $\left(x+\dfrac 1 x\right)^2=3$ then the value of $$x^{206}+x^{200}+x^{90}+x^{84}+x^{18}+x^{12}+x^{6}+1.$$

I'm trying to solve it like this $$x^2+\dfrac {1}{x^2}=1\text{ and }; x^6+\dfrac {1}{x^6}=-2$$
then solve the expression like this
$$(x^6+1)(x^{200}+x^{84}+x^{12}+1).$$
from here I am stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you manage to misspell a tag and create it?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury I dont know I think I was in hurry

Comment: how about following your method? $x^{12}+2x^6+1=0\implies (x^6+1)^2=0\implies x^6=-1$

Answer (score 12):

Hint: $$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2} = 1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x^4 = x^2-1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x^6=x^2x^4=-1.$$

Comment: That's not a hint, it's the answer.. :P

Comment: Nice. Though it took me a while to see how the second part led to the third part. I assume you are subbing in the x^2 from the first equation and the x^4 from the second to give $$\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)(x^2-1) = x^2 -2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = -1$$ or is there a simpler way of seeing how $$x^2x^4=-1$$?

Comment: $x^2 x^4 = x^2(x^2-1) = x^4-x^2=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Since, we have
$x^2=x^4+1 \implies x^4=x^2-1 \implies x^8 = -x^2$.

Then, we get

$x^6 = x^2 .x^4= -1 $

$x^{12} = x^6 . x^6 = 1$

$x^{18} = x^{12}.x^6= (1)(-1)=-1$

$x^{84}= x^{(18).(4)}.x^{12}=(-1)^4 .(1)=1$

$x^{90}=x^{(18)(5)}=(-1)^5=-1$

$x^{200}=x^{(12)(16)}.x^6.x^2=(1)^{16}.(-1).x^2=-x^2$

$x^{206}=x^{200}.x^6=(-x^2).(-1)=x^2$

Therefore,

$x^{206}+x^{200}+x^{90}+x^{84}+x^{18}+x^{12}+x^6+1=x^2-x^2 -1+1-1+1-1+1=0.$